# How to get error messages from Windows Imaging Component (WIC) using C++?

Tags: c++, image, wic

I've been experimenting with Windows Imaging Component (WIC) in C++ and while everything works I'd like to be able to display descriptive error messages when WIC fails to load or transform an image.

MSDN documents the various [error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but no way of getting the error message. The solution is probably a combination of LoadLibrary(...) to get the hModule followed by FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE, ...). I haven't found the correct DLL to load yet.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There isn't one, it is up to you to provide the error strings.  You only really need two, "Programmer error" and "Bad image file format".

Comment: I have already looked at WindowsCodes.dll with a binary viewer and it contains a fairly large number of strings concerning JPEG but they are similar or equal to the ones in the jpeglib library.
I can always roll my own but I wanted to try the API route first.

Comment: I searched all the files under the Windows directory for the contents of a particular error message (Bad stream data), but didn't find any matches. Therefore it's unlikely that these messages are currently available as part of a Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

Try `FormatMessage` with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`. A number of errors were added for Windows 8.x, so it likely returns more useful results on that platform.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/24/where-s-dxerr-lib.aspx) for an updated version of the venerable DXERR.LIB which includes WIC errors.